# Geometry Nodes Flower Grow - How can I bloom the flowers via animated vertex weights or vertex groups

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have this:

[image]

But cranking a value opens or closes all the flowers at the same time. Connecting a vertex group into the value doesn't do anything.

How should the nodes be arranged so that it works?

Thank you anybody willing to give a try.

[image]

(Note: The Dynamic Paint needs to be baked again for the GroundPlane in order for the flowers to work. The cache was stored on my disk and didn't transfer via the .blend)

Comment: Difficult, because instancing will make every instance be exactly the same. There is just one single flower variant being generated. "Realize Instances" before instancing doesn't actually do anything there (except maybe put all the petal instances on the same level, flattening the hierarchy a bit). The parallel loops feature that has been discussed would help here. Might try to generate all the flower parts N times based on points and individualize them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an implementation using the suggested technique of first generating points, calculating randomized positions, rotations, etc., then instance all the petals.

The stem curves are generated first by instancing a basic Bezier segment and then realizing the geometry. The flower bits are generated by getting the end point of the splines. Points for instance petals are made by instantiating a circle (like the original file), then realizing those too and instancing petals on the points.

I've tried grouping the sections in a meaningful way for easier understanding. Also had some fun and added a bit of wiggling based on scene time and a noise texture.
[image]

[image]

**Edit:** How to modify the blooming

In the last top-level block there is an input value "Open" to the flower node group, which controls the blooming progress for each flower. It can be a value between 0 and 1 for each of the input points.

I'm dividing the "Growth" value (from dynamic paint) by the "Density" vertex group, so that each flower reaches an Open value of 1 by the time it is fully grown. To further tweak the animation i use a Float Curve. The first curve point is set back a little so the flower stays closed for the first part of the growth, and then opens more rapidly, for a sort of "spring flower explosion" time-lapse effect.
[image]

Comment: Wow, so cool! Thank you. Yet, I still can't understand in where there one could for example offset the blooming of the flowers, so that they would be a bulb longer. Or how to make them grow slower or faster (well, that probably depends on the painted weight, right?)

Comment: Yeah the overall duration is determined by the dynamic paint falloff. If you make that wider the flowers will grow slower. I've added an explanation for tweaking the animation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But, what if I need to make the flowers bloom even more later than what the weights allow? Can it be pushed with some sort of math node in some specific point in the network? I tried something I thought would work but it just breaks everything :(

Comment: Ah, okay, found a workaround. Will post the finalized (but somewhat messy) .blend later, which is based on your awesome nodes, of course. I just can't fathom how to think like that, all the vector math and all.

Comment: Argh, having incredibly difficult time for randomizing color per flower :(

Comment: Dang it, also randomizing the size of flowers is very difficult :// (Thank you still for all the work with the nodes!)

Comment: Yes! Managed to randomize the scale while keeping the opening animation! .Blend coming soon

Comment: Randomizing color per flower tackled! Yes!

Answer (score 3):

It seems from your .blend, you are using only the DP weight for animation.

Given that, you could consider the growth of the flower as a whole, including stem-extension and petal-rotation, as a single action, controlled by different **mappings** of the DP weight. Naively:

[image]

..using the first half of the weight to grow the stem, and:

[image]

.. the second half of the weight to open the flower.

This is the stripped-back version, only illustrating the principle:

[image]

Yours will be more elaborate, the flowers will have to be realised; you will want to introduce some noise and overlap into the mapping to vary opening times, etc. etc.

But at first sight I can't see any block to that principle being used?

Personally I would suggest grouping up ['Stem Growth' by some index & parameter], ['Flower Opening' by some index and parameter],  and so on, into independently testable modules.

Comment: Wow, this was immensely helpful! And elegant! No need for capturing or transferring attributes (which I don't yet fully understand) - And the nodes in this are very easy to follow. Excellent stuff :)

Comment: @ManuJärvinen Thanks! Don't count your chickens.. things _might_ be more tricky with realized instances... any hitches, let us know..ry it out with simplified systems.

Comment: Indeed, I realized I still need a lot of help for rotating the petals open but at different times for each flower. The scaling an instance is so much more easier thing to do...

Comment: Ah, but the other answer's .blend seem to have that petal rotation at different times working! Let's see...

Comment: @ManuJärvinen quite right! It's the answer mine should have been. Crantisz' tick thoroughly deserved :D

Comment: Actually it was hard to pick one best answer, but then lukas_t came with that superb example, so the tick went there - However, your contribution illustrates very well how one should go about building a geometry nodes network with sense :)

Answer (score 2):

Since Blender's Geometry Nodes doesn't have loops for now, you cannot make a flower 100 times in a row. Also, you cannot modify the flower after it was instanced, because it will be very tricky in your case. So I suggest the following:

Instead of making the flower and when distribute it on surface, do the opposite thing: distribute the root thing on the surface and then add flowers and leafs on every root thing at the same time

[image]

Instance circles what you have used to spawn leaves, then realize instances to get individual points.

[image]

Then you will be able to rotate each leave according to weight:

[image]

[image]

Comment: There are no loop nodes, but of course you can create loops using the _Scene Time_ node with either the _Seconds_ or _Frames_ output.

Answer (score 1):

Based on lukas_t's superb [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/275754/8282) I implemented some needed features, even though the nodes became a bit non-elegant, I must say. But for some people this might be useful.

Download here:

[image]

[image]